# Scratch-org Definition: exceeded the allowed number of fields to track on a given entity

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org-definition-file

I'm having issues defining a scratch org that matches our production org.

In our production and sandbox instances, we have implemented Salesforce's [Field Audit Trail](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=field_audit_trail.htm&type=5) product. This allows us to have up to 60 fields auditable with a retention process of 10 years.

Although, when defining the [project-scratch-def.json](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm) with the feature `AddHistoryFieldsPerEntity:25`, the is a limit of 25 fields being audited.

- Has anyone else encountered this problem?
- Is there another way to have this product enabled as a feature in the
  project-scratch-def.json?
- Would a workaround be to manually go through the source for the project and switch the trackable variable on the fields?

any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 5):

I just found your question while looking up how to enable Field Audit Trail for my scratch org so that I could create a History Retention Policy.

In my search, I did find that you can add the feature "RetainFieldHistory" to your scratch org definition features:

```
"features": [
    "RetainFieldHistory"
]
```

and that seems to enable Field Audit Trail. I was able to create a History Retention Policy after that, and I tracked 38 fields on Account, which shouldn't be possible without Field Audit Trail (a limit of 20 I believe).

EDIT:
As of Spring '20, Salesforce has rightly updated the title of this feature to `FieldAuditTrail`. `RetainFieldHistory` will no longer work for enabling Field Audit Trail in your scratch org.